# Why multibootusb program not run?

Tags: dual-boot

I installed `multibootusb` in my Ubuntu 14.04. When I try to open the application window of multibootusb from dash, it takes my password,but the window never appears. Why does it do this?

Comment: What happens if you run the program using terminal? do you get any error?

Comment: where and how did you install it?

Comment: @Ravexina it show error `python3 multibootusb -c -i /media/alhelal/8835e212-1ef4-45d2-a2d1-59e4630f5f02/home/alhelal/Downloads/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso -t /dev/sdb1`  
`python3: can't open file 'multibootusb': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @Camden I have install using source code.

Comment: seems you are running it wrong... instead of multibootusb give the path to the multibootusb.

Comment: you are not running it where multibootusb is located, therefore, it will not work. try `cd /path/to/multibootusb`

Comment: Thanks. But it shows CalledProcessError. error link https://paste.ubuntu.com/25125944/

Comment: Can you consider an alternative tool to create a multiboot USB  drive? Can you consider the alternative to store the iso files separately and use the USB drive(s) as temporary devices and install each of them separately (and install another live system next time)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the new information you have provided to us in the comments. Otherwise it is highly likely that reviewers will close this as 'unclear'.